# Create public method to call a stored procedure in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I've created a public method in a class to call a query in any web page or web application.

The problem is I also want to create a a general public method in a class to call a stored procedure in any web page or web application.

I can call a query in any web page or web application using this.

```
clasCon Crud = new clasCon();

Crud.exeQry("Insert into names(fName,mName,lName)values('" + txtFname.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtMname.Text.Trim() + "','" + txtLname.Text.Trim() + "')")

public void exeQry(string qry)
{
    try
    {
        vbcon(); // connection
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, ConnS);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Query error! 
             :" + ex.Message + "'</script>");
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class needs to have a method which will accept the stored procedure name and list of OleDbParameters. In the method you create a new command with the stored procedure name as commandtext and add parameters to the command and execute the command.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Hi Sir yes thats actually what i want. Actually I've created this: but i dont know how to call or query the Stored Procedure parameters
public void execSP(string Sp)
{
 try
   {
  vbcon();
  cmd = new oldedbCommand(Sp, ConnS);
  cmd.commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.executeNonquery();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Query error! :" + ex.Message + "'</script>");
   }
    finaly
   {
   GC.collect();
   }
}

Comment: You should share your code in the question itself. Code in comments is not readable. Please also share what problem you are facing with that code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thank you for this. it helps me a lot. however i have one more question When I'm trying to call the method it gives me error "CS1501: No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the method as following.

```
public void ExecuteProcedure(string procName, List<OleDbParameter> parameters)
{
    try
    {
        vbcon(); // connection
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(procName, ConnS);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType. StoredProcedure;
        foreach(var parameter in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Query error! 
         :" + ex.Message + "'</script>");
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

This is how you call the method

```
clasCon Crud = new clasCon();
var procName = "MyProcedure";
var parameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@FName", txtFname.Text.Trim()));
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@MName", txtMname.Text.Trim()));
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@LName", txtLname.Text.Trim()));

Crud.ExecuteProcedure(procName, parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. it helps me a lot. however i have one more question When I'm trying to call the method it gives me error "CS1501: No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments"

Comment: @reygieprieto sorry about that... I just corrected my answer to resolve that error.